# Cannot connect to MariaDB through an OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: debian, openvpn, mariadb, tunnel

Similar to this issue [Unable to connect to MariaDB through an OpenVPN tunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/889942/unable-to-connect-to-mariadb-through-an-openvpn-tunnel)

I cannot connect to the MariaDB server through OpenVPN. The setup is -

- Ubuntu 20.04,
- mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.39-MariaDB,
- OpenVPN 2.4.7
- UFW Firewall

Findings and tries:

- Binding interface to the public IP works and I can connect directly but not through OpenVPN
- I tried port forwarding on UFW firewall when it listens on the main interface, did not connect through tunnel
- I tried bind-interface to 0.0.0.0, did not connect through tunnel
- I tried disabling UFW completely, did not connect through tunnel
- I tried removing bind-interface, did not connect through tunnel
- For testing purpose I started dummy listener on port 5000 (nc -l 5000), and did telnet from my openvpn client to this port, it connected to that port
- skip-networking is disabled

**Conclusion** - its not a firewall issue, because I can connect to SAMBA through OpenVPN, I also completely disabled firewall and the connection still cannot be made

This is the interface setup

```
root@machine:/home/myuser# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:ce:de:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet *PUBLIC IP* brd *PUBLIC IP BROADCAST* scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 64288sec preferred_lft 64288sec
    inet6 *PUBLIC IPV6* scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
102: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.1.1/24 brd 10.8.1.255 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c446:2ce1:c480:a740/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

TCP DUMP check - my client has IP 10.8.1.2

```
tcpdump -i tun1 -n port 3306
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun1, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes

09:26:53.954949 IP 10.8.1.2.59977 > 10.8.1.1.3306: Flags [S], seq 771542358, win 64240, options [mss 1286,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:26:54.969398 IP 10.8.1.2.59977 > 10.8.1.1.3306: Flags [S], seq 771542358, win 64240, options [mss 1286,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:26:56.979356 IP 10.8.1.2.59977 > 10.8.1.1.3306: Flags [S], seq 771542358, win 64240, options [mss 1286,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:27:00.989474 IP 10.8.1.2.59977 > 10.8.1.1.3306: Flags [S], seq 771542358, win 64240, options [mss 1286,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

Netstat

```
netstat -naplut | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      158452/mysqld
```

Mariadb 50-server config

```
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                  = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#port                   = 3306
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking

bind-address             = 0.0.0.0
```

UFW Status

```
ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
1194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
Samba                      ALLOW       10.8.1.0/24
16/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
1195                       ALLOW       Anywhere
1195/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       10.8.1.0/24
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
16/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1195 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1195/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as Debian 20.04.

Comment: Show the full `iptables-save` dump, there could be some masquerading involved.

Comment: @AlexD wups a small mistake, I meant Ubuntu, and yes I got it ! iptables-save showed this
iptables-save | grep 3306
-A PREROUTING -i tun1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3306
 after removing all of them the connection works ! Can you post your comment as the answer so I can accept it ... but what I dont understand why the masquerade still works when I run ufw disable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things at play:

- You have strict source restriction for 3306 to the range 10.8.1.0/24
- You have a VPN and VPNs sometimes insert masquerade rules into iptables automatically. This changes the client source IP to the host IP which gets blocked by the strict source IP restriction.
- UFW is just a wrapper around `iptables` and doesn't show the entire picture.  It simplifies adding simple rules but doesn't help at all with debugging the firewall configuration.

Comment: thanks, today I learned UFW is not doing everything what I thought it does, running ufw disable does not flush iptables, neither NAT rules